# View running extremely show with no filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a view that I recently created for a reporting purpose. The view consists of a CTE and 6 queries that are linked by "Union All."

When I run the following query, it takes less than a minute to complete (pulling 6000+ rows).

```
Select *
From myView
where Staffing_date between '12/01/2020' and '12/08/2020'
```

But when I run the following query, it takes forever. In fact, it took too long that I had to terminate executing the query after some time.

```
Select Top 100 *
From myView
```

Why would a view take so long to just pull up top 100 records, when it takes no time to pull more than 1000 records, given a date range? Where can I look to improve the performance of my view?

Below is the definition of the view. I have removed the columns from SELECT.

```
CREATE view [dbo].[MyView]
as

with ECCOTSignup as (
select ...
from ECC_splty e 
left join all_hire h on h.RscMaster_no_in = e.RscMaster_no_in and h.Rsc_No_In 
= e.rsc_no_in
left join OTStatus l on l.wstat_no_in = h.Wstat_no_in 
where h.Wstat_Abrv_Ch <> ''
and l.wstat_no_in in (107, 6)
)
select ...
from ECCOTSignup c
left join all_hire h on c.RscMaster_no_in = h.RscMaster_no_in and 
c.Staffing_Calendar_Date = h.Staffing_Calendar_Date
where h.Wstat_no_in = 103

union all

Select *
from ECCOTSignup

union all

select ...
from all_hire h
left join OTStatus l on l.wstat_no_in = h.Wstat_no_in
where h.Pos_Desc_Ch like '%ecc%'
and l.OTStatus = 'ECCOTWorked'
and h.Wstat_Abrv_Ch <> ''

union all

select ...
from OTStatus r
left join all_hire v on r.wstat_no_in= v.wstat_no_in
where r.OTStatus in ('OTSignup', 'ECCOTSignup')

union all

select ...
left join OTStatus l on l.wstat_no_in = v.Wstat_no_in
where l.OTStatus = 'otworked'

union all

select ...
from OTStatus r
left join all_hire v on r.wstat_no_in= v.wstat_no_in
where r.OTStatus in ('OTRemove')
```

Comment: What is the definition of the `VIEW`?

Comment: Also - using `TOP` *without* an explicit `ORDER BY` is useless - you'll get back 100 arbitrary rows since you didn't specify *which* top rows you want ....

Comment: @marc_s - Using TOP 100 with ORDER BY took 23 minutes. Way too slow.

Comment: Post the actual execution plans (preferably with [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) ) so we can see what's going on .....

Comment: Do you *need* all those `UNION ALL`s when it looks like a few `OR`s would fulfil the role better?

Comment: Your first query is filtering the resultset down to a single week. Your second query doesn't have any filter, and as such SQL Server is potentially (the execution plan would clarify) having to generate **all** the results before selecting 100 of them.

Comment: @Larnu - Thanks for the tip. I combined a couple using OR, but overall, Select TOP 100 does not appear to be affected.

Comment: What if you add an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @Larnu - I tried with ORDER BY, and it was still slow. The majority of slowness appears to be coming from the CTE portion. So I need to do something about it, it seems.